# Results of parent view are not getting displayed when attachment is used

Tags: 7, views

I have a page view with an attachment with following settings

- Attach to: Page
- Attachment position: After
- Inherit contextual filters: Yes
- Inherit exposed filters: Yes
- Access: Permission | View published content

When I apply filters to the parent view, I get expected result in an attachment but I'm not getting result of main view on page. But when I check in view's preview section, I get expected results for parent view but not for attachment.

What can be the problem?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1778568#comment-7589083